# R: avoid repeating $

Tags: r

I'm new here and new to R and I think I have a simple question but don't know how to name it so I can't find any help by searching the web.

I have a data set and want to form a new Data set with several variables from the first one.
The working code looks like this:

```
em.table2 <- data.frame(em.table$item1,em.table$item2,...[here are some more]...,em.table$item22)
```

In order to keep it more simple, I want to get rid of the "em.table$"-construction in front of every variable... unfortunately i don't know the function to do so...
I tried it like this, but it didn't work (and is a pretty embarrasing try i guess):

```
em.table2 <- data.frame(em.table$(item1,item2,item3,item4))
```

Anyone here to help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Or we could `em.table[ , c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4")`, read about `subset()`. Also, see [these posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=r+subset+a+dataframe).

Comment: Have a look at `transform()`

Comment: "I have a data set and want to form a new Data set with several variables from the first one." -> if this is your question, the title is really badly chosen. Remember it for next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `$` operator, try the following:

```
em.table2 <- em.table[,c("item1","item2","item3","item4")]
```

Comment: `em.table[,c("item1","item2","item3","item4")]` already gives the subset as dataframe object, no need to wrap it in data.frame again.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to delete the `data.frame` part.

Answer (score 0):

Try `with`

```
em.table2 <- with(em.table, data.frame(item1, item2, item3, item4))
```

But if you just want to `subset` the data, there are better solutions.